# Bidding Collusion Question: Probability of Identical Bids

Tags: probability, modeling, dataset

I was asked this question. My initial conclusion is that there isn't enough information to calculate the probability. I would appreciate it if anyone could provide provide their insight.

Scenario:
Department of Defense is looking to purchase a good. Department of Defense has determined that a fair price is 1.0000 and told vendors of this value. Eight vendors submitted independent bids to provide the desired good.

What are the odds/probability that three vendors would submit the exact same bid (see below)?

```
0.7700
0.7999
1.1120
0.7000
1.4262
0.6840
0.7000
0.7000
```

Comment: Is this under "real world" assumptions or is it a word problem? Because of the way it's phrased, most of it would be an exercise in game theory.

Comment: Real world assumptions.

Comment: People often bid round numbers, or just below round numbers (to underbid people who bid round numbers); if the fair price is known and they experience similar costs (e.g. work in the same economy with similar labor and equipment costs), I'd expect a lot of them to choose similar round bids. So I'd say "pretty likely" but there's no real way to guess how likely only on the information given.

Answer (score 1):

You're right: as stated, there isn't enough information in the question to calculate a probability.

However if you wanted to make assumptions, you could take one of two main routes:

1. As user Andy Blankterz mentioned in the comments, you could assume payoff functions for each of the bidders. This reduces the problem to a first-price auction. It might be worth mentioning here that first-price auctions are suboptimal for the seller, from what I remember of auction theory.
2. You could assume probability distributions over bidders' behavior. This reduces the problem to something like the birthday problem. Keep in mind that the probability of *exact* equality is zero in the continuous case.

You could also combine these two by assuming stochastic payoffs (e.g. bidders don't know the payoffs for certain) or otherwise incorporating randomness into the first model. This could turn out to be a nontrivial problem to solve. If you're stone-cold confident in your analysis and probability skills, the definitive book on the subject is *[Putting Auction Theory to Work](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521536723)* by Paul Milgrom.